# chrome extension click event

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have this mission to build an extension that react to a click and then it searchs for all the  tags in the opened tab and have them in a border..

here is my files:
mainfest:

```
{
  "name": "My First Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "The first extension that I made.",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"  
  },  

  "permissions": [
    "tabs", 
    "http://*/*", 
    "https://*/*"   
  ],
  "background_page": "popup2.html"

}
```

background:

```
<style>
    .ul_style{
    border: 1px solid;
    position: relative;
    width: 25%;
}

.style2{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    border: 1px solid green;
    }

    #url{
    width: 500px;
    }
</style>
<script src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
    function ul_checker(){
        $('ul').addClass('ul_style');
        $('ul').append('<div class="close">X</div>');
    $('.close').addClass('style2');
}

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(ul_checker);

</script>
```

what is missing in my code, and another words.. how we get the mission completed?

Comment: you think wrong, you need to execute the script in the tab and not in background page from extension

Comment: look at [this](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a popup enabled click event will not get fired.

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html